Nutrient requirements in heterotrophs and surface area?
I'm writing a report for Year 11 Biology and I'm having trouble linking my experiment to the topic "nutrient requirements of heterotrophs".
My experiment in summary: Investigating "effects of the surface area of a potato on the height of bubbles produced during a chemical reaction". It involves dicing potatoes (of various surface areas) and placing them in hydrogen peroxide where there will be an interaction between the enzyme catalase and the substrate (hydrogen peroxide). The more bubbles the more chemical reactions have occured.
I don't fully understand how to link this to heterotrophic nutrient requirements, am I supposed to write about nutrient requirements (biomolecules) -> metabolic processes (cellular respiration) -> catalase is produced to break down harmful hydrogen peroxide? Or nutrient requirements (biomolecules) -> digestion and absorption of nutrients requires low surface area because ____?
Sorry if this is worded badly, I'd appreciate any help!
